# Update Swift package manager from terminal when there is no package.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have a project which has multiple targets such as:

I am also using all three ways of dependencies: Pods, Carthage and SPM. These multiple targets has different dependencies, let me try to show by below example:

MainApp.xcodeproj

T1.xcodeproj (uses SPM1, SPM2 dependency)

T2.xcodeproj (uses SPM3, SPM4 dependency)
.
.
.
.

Tn.xcodeproj (uses SPM5, SPM6 dependency)

Also, I don't have package.swift file at root folder for my project, and every target generally will have it's own package.resolve file.

Now, My problem is I can't update my SPM dependencies from terminal as we are using a CI/CD tool to automatically update the SPM dependencies. Can anyone suggest how can I update SPM dependencies of multiple targets from terminal.

I hope my question is well explained and illustrated.

Thanks